# How to close Esp32 Mail Client Log Print?

Tags: esp32, email-client, error-log

I am working on sending mail with esp32. I am using esp mail client library. Sending mail part works very well, but sometimes it prints error log from serial. Serial is also connected to an external device so these logs are giving me big trouble. I did smtp.debug(0), but I couldn't prevent this output. The error message it gives is as follows: "[499274][E][vfs_api.cpp:104] open(): /littlefs/tze.txt does not exist, no permits for creation".
Is there a way to completely turn off error log messages for ESP32? I am using VS Code as compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. `#define ARDUHAL_LOG_LEVEL ARDUHAL_LOG_LEVEL_NONE` in esp32-hal-log.h
I defined it as this didn't solve my problem. Then I did `#define ARDUHAL_LOG_LEVEL (-1)` and the problem was solved.